# highcharts with more series that start from different x value

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i have a chart with 5 different series to represent. One of them has to start from a point of the categories that is not the first one! 
The categories are represented by an array like this ("200910", "200911", ...... "201407")
so i assigned to the serie an array like this:

serie1.push(["201201", 12345], ["201202", 1234], ....);
options.series[0].data = serie1;

but the chart starts always from the first point of the category that is "200910". i think that it does not interpret the value on the x axis
Where do i'm wrong?

thank you very much
Cinzia

Comment: You need to use index of categories, not string.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! THE PROBLEM WAS THAT!!! I used the index of the array instead of the string element

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

http://jsfiddle.net/50a8ajLv/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.05,
        maxPadding: 0.05
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [0, 29.9],
            [1, 71.5],
            [3, 106.4]
        ]
    },
    {
        data: [
            [4, 7],
            [5, 12],
            [9, 60]
        ]
    }]
});
```

A list of arrays with two values. In this case, the first value is the x value and the second is the y value. **If the first value is a string, it is applied as the name of the point**, and the x value is incremented following the above rules.

*From:* https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series